Cannot deploy strapi app to cpanel using phusion passenger
I have old version of cpanel having node 16. I am trying to deploy strapi app but it keeps on failing


I have just create a zip of code and than uploaded it to document root, after that I click on ensure dependencies and getting the error after this. I am using Cpanel With Phusion Passenger
